# MFC - Changing dialog item focus programmatically

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2005

I have a Modeless dialog which shows a bunch of buttons; some of these are customized to draw stuff with GDI.
Now, when the user clicks on a customized one under certain conditions, a message box appears to alert user of the error and this is fine.
The problem is that after accepting the Message Box (showed as MB_ICON_ERROR), everywhere I click in the dialog, I always get the error message as if the whole dialog send the message to the customized button and the only way to get rid this is to press tab and give the focus to another control.
This is a strange behaviour and knowing why happens wouldn't be bad, but a simple workaround for now should do the job.
Since the moment that is probably a matter of focus, I've tried to set it on another control (in the owner dialog) by doing:`GetDlgItem( IDC_BTN_ANOTHER_BUTTON )->SetFocus();`
and then, inside the customized control by adding:`KillFocus( NULL );`but had no results.
How should I use these functions?
Thanks in advance.

PS: if I comment the AfxMessageBox, the control does not show this bizarre behaviour.
**EDIT**
I'll show some code as requested.

```
// This is where Message Box is popping out. It is effectively inside the dialog code.
void CProfiloSuolaDlg::ProcessLBtnDownGraphProfilo(PNT_2D &p2dPunto)
{
    // m_lboxProfiles is a customized CListBox
    if(m_lboxProfiles.GetCurSel() == 0)
    {
        // This profile cannot be modified.
        /*
        CString strMessage;

        strMessage.Format( _T("Default Profile cannot be edited.") );
        AfxMessageBox( strMessaggio, MB_ICONERROR );
        */

        return;
    }
    // Selecting a node from sole perimeter.
    SelectNodo(p2dPoint);
}
```

Actually, the message is commented to keep the dialog working.

```
// This is inside the customization of CButton
void CMyGraphicButton::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    PNT_2D p2dPunto;
    CProfiloSuolaDlg* pDlg = (CProfiloSuolaDlg*)GetParent();     

    m_pVD->MapToViewport(point,p2dPunto);
    switch(m_uType)
    {
    case GRF_SEZIONE:
        pDlg->ProcessLBtnDownGraphProfilo(p2dPunto);
        break;
    case GRF_PERIMETRO:
        pDlg->ProcessLBtnDownGraphPerimetro(p2dPunto);
        break;
    }
    CButton::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

Comment: I'm betting the problem is a bug in your code, but, you don't show any for us to provide feedback.

Comment: Well, code is pretty big, can you point me somewhere so I can show you the portion you need.

Comment: I would guess the problem is in or close to the code that handles your click event(s).  But, you should post whatever code you think may be problematic.

Comment: I've posted the code involved in the problem.

Comment: Your question is difficult for me to understand, and your code is even worse, considering it's not in English. Anyway, `SetFocus` is not the correct way of changing the focused control on a dialog. You need to send the [`WM_NEXTDLGCTL` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645432.aspx) instead.

Comment: I think your base class call in the button handler may be the problem.  Have you tried un-commenting the call to the message box and commenting the base class call to OnLButtonDown?

Comment: Whops sorry, I forgot to translate it!

Comment: @rrirower Gotcha! You can write down the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are handling the button down event in the button handler for the custom control, you don't need to call the base class.  Just comment out *CButton::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point)*.